# React Native - Expo - Crash on the android application when I try to display a PDF

Tags: react-native, pdf, expo

I have been trying for some time to solve a critical bug in the expo application. On the Android version, every time I try to display a pdf I have a crash without error. To display the pdf, I used both rn-pdf-reader-js and a simple webview. I even tested with a simple PDF like: https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf and it still cracks. The most important thing to mention is that this crash does not reproduce on any device, so far I have managed to reproduce it on several Samsung models (ex: Galaxy s22 & s21 with android 14) as well as on Redmi Note 9t (with Android 12).

I am attaching a list of dependencies:
{
"expo": "^48.0.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"rn-pdf-reader-js": "^4.1.1",
"react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
}.

I can also attach the time of the crash from the adb log:
01-12 10:24:10.023 26125 26125 F DEBUG : Cmdline: com.test.test
01-12 10:24:10.023 26125 26125 F DEBUG : pid: 23250, tid: 23369, name: RenderThread >>> com.test.test <<<
01-12 10:24:10.085 1407 26131 W ActivityManager: crash : com.test.test,10701
01-12 10:24:10.086 1407 26128 W ActivityTaskManager: Force finishing activity com.test.test/.MainActivity

I tried to display a simple pdf on the Android version using React Native - Expo.